# Merge datasets where dates are not within a range of each other

Tags: r, excel

I have two sets of data. The datasets have the following columns: `Patient_name`, `Drug_administered`, `Date_of_administration`. There are two drugs: X and Y.

I want to delete the rows from Set1 in which a patient got drug Y (in Set2) within 14 days of getting drug X (in Set1).

Here is what the datasets look like:

Set1

```
Patient_name Drug_administered Date_of_administration 
 A               x                3/6/2010 
 A               x                4/7/2011 
 A               x                4/8/2011 
 B               x                6/18/2014 
 B               x                6/19/2014 
 B               x                7/19/2014
```

Set2

```
  Patient_name   Drug_administered  Date_of_administration
   A               y                 3/6/2009
   A               y                 4/18/2011
   A               y                 4/8/2014
   B               y                 6/18/2013
   B               y                 6/19/2013
   B               y                 7/19/2013
```

For instance, I would like to delete the second entry of patient A in set1, because he received drug Y within 14 days of receiving drug X.

How can I do this, in Excel or R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
colnames(set1) <- c("ID", "x.given", "x.date")
colnames(set2) <- c("ID", "y.given", "y.date")

both <- merge(set1, set2, by="ID")

subset(both, subset=abs(as.Date(x.date) - as.Date(y.date)) > 14))
```

It joins the datasets on the ID column then subsets to where the absolute difference in administration dates is greater than 14 days, thereby removing cases where x and y were administered within 14 days of each other.